# C# - Exclude directories and files from Directory.GetDirectories() and Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, file-io, getfiles, getdirectories

I need to count files and directories inside a specified directory path. But I want to exclude **.git** folder and files inside this folder from being counted. I tried -

```
int maxCount = Directory.GetFiles(loadedDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length + Directory.GetDirectories(loadedDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

And for excluding .git, I can write -

```
Directory.GetDirectories(loadedDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(item => !item.EndsWith(".git")).ToArray().Length;
```

> This will exclude .git directory, But how can I prevent **files** (present inside .git directory) being counted?

As per my knowledge, GetDirectories() deals with only folders not with files and GetFiles() deals only with files without caring what directories excluded by GetDirectories().

Comment: Inspect what “item” really is and update the Where condition appropriately.

Comment: There is nothing in those methods that will do the filtering for you. You will have to filter out any paths you don't want in the result, *or* you will have to make many calls in order to grab only the folders/files you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this:

```
    var all = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var allCount = all.Count();
    var noGit = all.Where(p =>  !p.Contains(@"\.git\") && !p.EndsWith(@"\.git")).ToArray();
    var noGitCount = noGit.Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following. Comments included with code

```
// List of Folders to be ignore, .git ones
var foldersToIgnore = Directory.GetDirectories(path,".git",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
// list of files, excludes ones in .git folder
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(x=>!foldersToIgnore.Any(c=>x.StartsWith(c)));
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(x=>!foldersToIgnore.Any(c=>x.StartsWith(c)));
// Count
var maxCount = files.Count() + directories.Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

As MSDN states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8):

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Therefore, you should be better off by doing something like the following:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
var filesCount = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count(file => !file.DirectoryName.Contains(".git"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this solution:

```cs
var pathToIgnore = loadedDirectoryPath + ".git";
int count =
    Directory.GetFiles(loadedDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => !d.StartsWith(pathToIgnore))
    .Concat(Directory.GetDirectories(loadedDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => !d.StartsWith(pathToIgnore)))
    .ToArray()
    .Count();
```

Note that this solution will only let you specify one folder to exclude, but it's trivial to adapt it to works with multiple folders to exclude.

Let me know if it will be useful.